# Create a Generic Method For multiple like classes

Tags: c#, generics, model-view-controller

I am trying to refactor some code and we currently don't use AutoMapper or any mapping tool.

How would I create a generic method for the below?

I have about 8 different ViewModels passing similar data.

```
    public static AppUser Create(RegisterViewModel model)
    {
        return new AppUser()
        {
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            Email = model.Email,              
        };
    }

    public static AppUser Create(TeamUserViewModel model)
    {
        return new AppUser()
        {
            FirstName = model.FirstName,
            LastName = model.LastName,
            Email = model.Email,
        };
    }
```

I was thinking something like :

```
    public static AppUser Create<T>(T Model)
    {
    }
```

Comment: If those models share properties, why not use [inheritance](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/tutorials/inheritance) to build a parent class with all the shared properties and then use that one in your method's signature?

Comment: In AutoMapper that method is called `Map` :) https://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Getting-started.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes you could do something like that. The problem is you won't be able to access the variables of `FirstName`, `LastName`, or `Email`. What you should do is create a class like the following

```cs
public class BaseClass
{
   public string FirstName;
   public string LastName;
   public string Email;
}
```

Now have both your `RegisterViewModel` and `TeamUserViewModel` extend this class like so

```cs
public class RegisterViewModel : BaseClass
{
   // specialized information here
}
```

Now in your new function, you can specify the type of `T` like so

```cs
public static AppUser Create<T>(T model) where T : BaseClass
{
   // Stuff here
}
```

and now you will have access to each of those variables/methods defined in the `BaseClass`. The benefit is that each of your extended classes are not constrained to just those few variables.

Furthermore if you want to perform specialized logic for each model, you can do the following:

```cs
if(typeof(T) == typeof(TeamUserViewModel))
{
   // Perform action
}
else if (typeof(T) == typeof(RegisterViewModel))
{
   // Perform different action
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can do the following:

- Make a base class that your view model inherit from that contains FirstName, LastName, Email. Use the base class in your parameter for the Create method: `public static AppUser Create(BaseViewModelBaseClass model)`
- Make an interface called IUserDetails that your view models implement and make that your parameter `public static AppUser Create(IUserDetailsViewModel Model)`